I want to know how to use the hint. Exercise 14.c in "Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms" [ Fourth Edition ] by Cox, Little and O'Shea.
I am reading "Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms" [ Fourth Edition ] by Cox, Little and O'Shea.
While I have solved Exercise 14.c , I don't understand the role of the hint of Exercise 14.c at all.
Since I didn't use the hint (I didn't consider the three cases separately.) , I want to know how to use the hint to solve Exercise 14.c.
If we use the idea of the hint, can we solve the general version of this exercise?
Hence , the authors wrote the hint?


My solution:
The following pictures show that $(u,v)$ can be any point in the disk $u^2+v^2\leq 36$.
I "locked" the joint between the length 2 and length 1 arms to form a straight angle, but allowed the other joint to move freely.



pls try to avoid images and type in LaTeX

(1) Your Solution is indeed correct.
It does work here , though you have given only the intuitive outline. You will have to give the angles necessary to generate all $(u,v)$ values.
In that sense , your method is slightly complicated though satisfactorily workable.

(2) There are certain cases where your method might require more work or might not even work. Eg 1 When the lengths are $4,10,4$ & we lock the inner $10+4=14$ , then we can not generate all $(u,v)$ values.
Eg 2 When the lengths are $1,1,3$ & we lock the outer $1+1=2$ , then we encounter similar difficulties.
In that sense , the hint is slightly more generalized & always workable.

(3) What the Author is hinting is :

(3A) We lock $3+2=5$ & then confirm that we can generate all values where $16=(5-1)^2 < u^2+v^2 < (5+1)^2=36$
(3B) We lock $2-1=1$ & then confirm that we can generate all values where $4=(3-1)^2 < u^2+v^2 < (3+1)^2=16$
(3C) We lock $3-2=1$ & then confirm that we can generate all values where $0=(1-1)^2 < u^2+v^2 < (1+1)^2=4$

Even  though there are other ways to generate some $(u,v)$ values , we lock at either ${0}^\circ$ or ${180}^\circ$ , leaving only one angle to worry about.
Basically , we are making $X>(u,v)>Y$ where $X$ & $Y$ are like adding & subtracting scalar real numbers , except for one value which will be at some angle & we will use trigonometric vector calculations to add that.
In that sense , the hint is slightly easier to work with though not necessarily the only unique way.

Prem, thank you very much for your answer and your edit!
